# ExpressionEngine content template

Tags: templates, expressionengine

i have created channel called "news" and the channel field.

i have created template group called "news".

in news template group, there are "index" and "single" template.

what i want to do is when user go to url mydomain.com/news, it will show all the news with template from "index" template,

but if user go/ click to url mydomain.com/news/first-post, it will show the post with template from "single" template.

how can i achieve this?
i have tried to choose "single" template from "page" tab when i publish new content, but it didn't work.
the content url still show the "index" template

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL routing in ExpressionEngine is as follows:

`http://www.yourdomain.com/template-group/template/entry-url-title`

It makes sense from an EE perspective that the news template is being shown when you go to `mydomain.com/news/first-post`. EE is looking for a template called `first-post` in the `news` template group. You can fix this in one of two ways:

1) Change the url you're looking for to `mydomain.com/news/single/first-post`. This should show your post.

2) If you don't want to show "single" in the URL, setup a condition in the main news template as follows:

```
{if segment_2}
{embed="news/single"}
{if:else}
... rest of your template code
{/if}
```

To keep this template cleaner, you might even want to create a news/main template so you can

```
{if segment_2}
{embed="news/single"}
{if:else}
{embed="news/main"}
{/if}
```

Up to you.

Comment: yeah, i think the second option is what i'm looking for.

thanks imjared